# C# action invoke is changing `this`

Tags: c#, debugging, delegates, action

### TL;DR

If a C# `Action` referencing a class method still has a reference to the original `Target`, then why is `this` being changed when I invoke the `Action` and set breakpoints in that method?

### More Context

I have the following setup in a .NET project:

```cs
// MyClass.cs
public class MyClass
{
    private float _someValue = -1f;
    private int _instanceId = 12345;

    public void Method()
    {
        Updater.Instance.RegisterUpdate(_instanceId, doStuff);
    }
    private void doStuff(float deltaTime)
    {
        // Do stuff with _someValue
    }
}

// Updater.cs
public class Updater
{
    public static Updater Instance = new();

    private readonly List<Action<float>> _updateActions = new();

    public void RegisterUpdate(int instanceId, Action<float> updateAction)
    {
        // Validation...
        _updateActions.Add(updateAction);
    }
    public void Update()
    {
        foreach (Action<float> action in _updateActions)
            action.Invoke(Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Essentially, `Updater` wraps a list of registered `Action`s, and invokes them all when `Update` is called.

In Visual Studio, I can set breakpoints in `MyClass.doStuff()`, and they are getting hit when `Updater.Update()` is called. Unfortunately, while   paused on a breakpoint, I get no value when I hover over the value of `_someValue`, nor is the field even mentioned in the Locals Window, and when I enter `_someValue` in the Immediate Window, I get "The identifier `_someValue` is not in the scope". In addition, the `this` value in the Locals Window is of type `Updater`, not `MyClass`.

And yet, everything is working fine. The conditional logic inside `doStuff` that works with `_someValue` is still working as expected when I step through, I just can't inspect the values as I step, which makes things difficult to debug. Also, when I go up the call stack to `Updater.Update` and inspect the current element of `_updateActions`, I can see that its `Target` property is correctly set to the instance of `MyClass`. So what is happening here? Trying to figure out what `this` is feels like JavaScript crap lol, not C#.

Comment: While you are inside functions of a class, `this` points to the enclosing class of the function. When you call `Updater.update`, then `this` is of type `Updater`. While inside `doStuff`, `this` will be `MyClass`.

Comment: @knittl That's what I expected also. But I'm saying that while inside `doStuff`, `this` is actually referring to `Updater`

Comment: Please provide a full [mcve]. What you describe cannot happen.

Comment: @NineBerry I tried to provide a MWE above in my question; only thing I left out was code to call `Updater.Update`, but that could be anywhere. There were technically some syntax errors, but I just edited those. It might be worth mentioning that this code is running in Unity scripts, so in my project, the `Updater.Update` method is actually being called by the Unity engine, not any of my code.

Comment: The code provided doesn't compile because there are still syntax errors which suggests that you have not copied it from a test project but invented on the go. Follow the instructions on how to provide a [mcve].

Comment: @NineBerry You are correct, I invented this on the go; the actual code is quite a bit more complicated and relies on the Unity engine, so rather than slash a bunch of code I just built this MWE up. The core logic is still the same. I just edited my answer to fix the lingering compiler errors. The only thing missing now should be code to call `Updater.Update`, which again could be anything (a unit test, static `Main` method, Unity `Update` message or wherever).

Comment: Have you reproduced the issue using the exact code from the question?

Comment: The posted code doesn't reproduce the issue https://imgur.com/a/FM4qub2

Comment: @NineBerry On further investigation, it looks like the issue is that, in my real code, the `doStuff` method is a local method defined inside `Method`. When I make `doStuff` a full method (as in my snippet above), then `this` is of the correct `MyClass` type, as you observed. Also, I can only repro this behavior in Unity components, not in vanilla C# classes, so this may be a result of the Mono compiler that Unity uses on the backend. Thank you for encouraging me to dig deeper.

Comment: FWIW, given my reputation score on this site, I think one can assume that I understand what a minimum working example is and tried to provide one. Obviously I did a poor job of it in this case, but I quickly edited my answer based on the above comments and have now followed up with the real issue. Continuing to downvote my question without explanation is extremely rude and discouraging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was something in my actual code that was not captured in the minimum working example in my question. That is, in my real code, `doStuff` was a local function *inside of* `Method`. If `doStuff` is a separate method, as in my question, then `this` is of the correct `MyClass` type. Strangely, I can only repro the `this`-changing behavior of local functions in Unity components, not in vanilla C# classes, so this may be a result of the Mono compiler that Unity uses on the backend.

Anyway, thank you to the commenters for helping me get here. Hopefully this helps someone in the future.